# Android transition animation linear cross fade effect

Tags: android, animation, transition

I need to make cross fade effect on two bitmaps in a way that first bitmap is being replaced by the second one linearly from top to bottom. In other words first bitmap should
dissapear from top to bottom and in it's place second bitmap should appear.
There are many examples with cross fade with animations (changing alpha), or using TransitionDrawable, but i was not able to find the one i am looking for.
Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know, try this custom class:

```
public class MyView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Bitmap mBitmap0;
    private Bitmap mBitmap1;
    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private float mY;
    private Rect mRect;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mBitmap0 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b0);
        mBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b1);
        mMatrix = new Matrix();
        mRect = new Rect();
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap0.getWidth(), mBitmap0.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        mMatrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xff0000aa);
        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        Rect r = mRect;
        r.set(0, 0, mBitmap0.getWidth(), (int) (mY * mBitmap0.getHeight()));
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap0, r, r, null);
        r.set(0, (int) (mY * mBitmap1.getHeight()), mBitmap1.getWidth(), mBitmap1.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1, r, r, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TBAnimation anim = new TBAnimation();
        startAnimation(anim);
    }

    class TBAnimation extends Animation {
        public TBAnimation() {
            mY = 0;
            setDuration(2000);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            mY = interpolatedTime;
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

or this one (has narrow fade out strip):

```
public class MyView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int FADE_HEIGHT = 32;
    private Bitmap mBitmap0;
    private Bitmap mBitmap1;
    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private float mY;
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint0;
    private LinearGradient mShader;
    private Paint mPaint1;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mBitmap0 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b1);
        mBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b0);
        mMatrix = new Matrix();
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint0 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, FADE_HEIGHT, 0x00ffffff, 0xffffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint0.setShader(mShader);
        mPaint1 = new Paint();
        mPaint1.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap0.getWidth(), mBitmap0.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        mMatrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xff0000aa);
        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        Rect r = mRect;
        int y = (int) (mY * mBitmap0.getHeight());

        // draw new bitmap on top
        r.set(0, 0, mBitmap0.getWidth(), y + FADE_HEIGHT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap0, r, r, null);

        // draw old bitmap strip fading out
        canvas.saveLayer(0, y, mBitmap1.getWidth(), y + FADE_HEIGHT, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, y);
        r.set(0, 0, mBitmap1.getWidth(), FADE_HEIGHT);
        canvas.drawRect(r, mPaint0);
        canvas.restore();
        r.set(0, y, mBitmap1.getWidth(), y + FADE_HEIGHT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1, r, r, mPaint1);
        canvas.restore();

        // draw old bitmap on bottom
        r.set(0, y + FADE_HEIGHT, mBitmap1.getWidth(), mBitmap1.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1, r, r, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap tmp = mBitmap0;
        mBitmap0 = mBitmap1;
        mBitmap1 = tmp;
        TBAnimation anim = new TBAnimation();
        startAnimation(anim);
    }

    class TBAnimation extends Animation {
        public TBAnimation() {
            mY = 0;
            setDuration(3000);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            mY = interpolatedTime;
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks pskink - this is exactly what i wanted to achieve!

To add whole animation more smoothness it would be good to make an effect so that this two bitmaps penetrate each other on the "line of touch" - maybe you know how to do that also? a linear gradient perhaps?

Comment: @lothar it can be done but its a little bit complicated, see my edited answer

Comment: Works like charm, even better effect than previous one. BIG thanks for help